# my model binding is working even If I didn't show it in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have a form that can be reached by different ways. In the URL, if user comes with ?data=johndoe (example), I didn't want to deal with another property, so I didn't show it to user and I don't care of this property. Because I use the same form and the same Controller when user submit the form, I just want to receive that other property to null in controller ands then treat it differently.

So

I have a model that I init and return to a form,

```
public class MyModel
{
public int selectedValue {get;set;}
public string data {get;set;}

public MyModel(){
this.selectedValue = 5;
}
}

public ActionResult Index(){
MyModel model = new MyModel(){};
Return View(model);
}
```

On the view, I decided to not show the selectedValue in order to receive it as null value when user submit the form, so in the form I just

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.data)
```

And nothing for the selectedValue.

Then In the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
// here I get model.selectedValue = 5, WHY?
}
```

I want to get model.selectedValue at null If I didn't use it in the form, it looks normal, no?

If it's normal, why and How can I fix this issue from the razor page?
Any clean idea on how Can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 5 because you set it in the constructor

```
public MyModel(){
    // comment this line to get rid of 5
    // this.selectedValue = 5;  
}
```

You also won't get it set to `null`, because you use `int` which is a value type that doesn't have `null` as value. You can use nullable int `int?` or some default value, like `-1` to indicate there was no selection.

Comment: so I have to override the 5 in the razor view and put in as hidden field?

Comment: Why do you set it to 5 anyway? What's its magic meaning? Please see my edit of what I was trying to say. No other action is required (no hidden fields)

Comment: @clement, better make it nullable and set it to null when you don't need it.

Comment: The answer is "don't do that". Using 2 view templates with different values would be better that setting every MyModel() instance selectedValue = 5, and then undoing it. The model binder basically does new MyModel(), then copies collection parameters to the object (if they match by name).

Comment: @RaulNoheaGoodness There is +300 lines of cshtml to maintain, so no, I really prefer eusing one single view. Maybe two different controllers can do the trick but well

Comment: Then keep the one template, one controller, and pass an extra parameter on the querystring for the different conditional logic. You can leave selectedValue == null or 0, and only set to 5 in the different case (writing a hidden input tag)

Comment: @oleksii When I set @Html.Hidden("responsibleSelected", null), modelbinding still bind 5

Comment: Have you commented the line? Another thought is try hard refresh for browser (CTRL+R or CTRL+F5)

Comment: I finally put <input id="responsibleSelected" name="responsibleSelected" type="hidden" value="" /> the @Html.Hidden("responsibleSelected", null) was definitively not working

Answer (score 1):

It's not passed from the form, but a new instance of `MyModel` is still generated, and, right there in your constructor, you're setting the value to 5.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int selectedValue {get;set;}
    public string data {get;set;}

    public MyModel() {
        // MyModel.selectedValue will always be 5 unless specified otherwise
        this.selectedValue = 5;
    }
}
```

> I want to get model.selectedValue at null

in which case, change your model to:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int? selectedValue {get;set;}
    public string data {get;set;}
}
```

if you can't change the Model (eg third-party) then you'll have to provide a value in the view "fix this issue in the razor view".   You could set it to zero or some other magic-number (use a constant...) to indicate a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized the variable `selectedValue` in the constructor.

When model binding creates the instance, this constructor is also called, which means the variable `selectedValue` in the `Index` action method is equal to 5.